# Core java need solution (both .dat files are encrypted)

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    int x;
    int y;
    int xo;
    DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(
            "file1.dat"));
    DataInputStream input1 = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(
            "file2.dat"));



    while (input.available() > 0) {

        x = input.readInt();
        // System.out.println("File 1 "+x);
        y = input1.readInt();
        // System.out.println("File 2 "+y);

         xo=(x^y);
         System.out.println(""+xo);
    } }
```

I need to XOR .dat files with each other to get clear text simply we need to decrypt the client and server log file in order to check the user who loged in to the server, server generated log file which are encrypted

Current Output:

```
1281 
7282 
3861
```

Output Needed:

```
ALICE 
BOB 
FRANK
```

Comment: please also provide input files

Comment: `available()` is not a test for end of stream. See the Javadoc. Your read loop should run until `EOFException` is caught.

Answer (score 1):

You're converting the character number (say, 65 for A) to string ("65") and outputting the number. You're also adding a line break after it by using `println`. You want to output the *character* ('A'), and probably without any line break (`print`):

```
System.out.print((char)xo);
```

You're also reading unsigned `short`s, which is not likely to be correct, but it depends entirely on how the file is created. Usually XOR obfuscation of text is done at the character level, so you probably want [`DataInputStream#readChar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readChar--). So for instance:

```
char x, y, xo;
// ...
while (input.available() > 0) {

    x = input.readChar();
    // System.out.println("File 1 "+x);
    y = input1.readChar();
    // System.out.println("File 2 "+y);

    xo = (char)(x ^ y);
    System.out.print(xo);
}
```

...but again, it depends on how the files were created. It's entirely possible to XOR blocks of other sizes — `byte`, `int`, etc...

Comment: Bro!! i already did this but i think the problem is with the reading method i used kindly suggest me what to do when i have to read encrypted dat file and xor that file with another encrypted dat file to get the answer in plane text

Comment: @ahsanmurtaza: Normally with XOR obfuscation (it's a bit much to call it encryption), it's done per-byte. So you want to read bytes, so that's [`DataInputStream#readByte`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readByte--) (or just [`InputStream#read`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--)).

Comment: @ T.J.Crowder bro i am new in java kindly give me a piece of code to use to read dat file as byte, it will be highly appreciated

Comment: it producing an error on  xo = x ^ y; what to do now ??

Comment: thanks a lot brother i am still working on it to get the things done much appreciated your efforts ;)

Comment: The line in question needs to be `xo = (char)(x ^ y)`, because `^` yields an `int` result, like all other binary operators on operands narrower than `int`. Not because `^` isn't defined over chars. It is.

Comment: @EJP: Thanks. I thought it was but was rushing and decided to just cover all bases. :-)

Comment: @ahsanmurtaza: See my edit folding in EJP's comment above.